# How to increase battery performance?

Tags: release-loki, power, battery, thinkpad

I am using elementary OS 0.4 Loki on my LENOVO ThinkPad Edge E125. Everything is fine except battery performance. The battery lasts hardly 1 hour what was previously almost 3 hours. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

elementaryOS needs far more battery power then some other distros. You pay the price for the shiny appearance. In my experience Peppermint or lubuntu last about double the time than elementaryOS does on the same machine. Switching off discrete video card and using integrated video, however, will improve battery performance radically on some machines which have double video option feature. All the rest wizardry (with powertop etc) did not seriously improve battery performance on my ThinkPad.